# Is it possible to increment the font size?

Tags: fontsize

Is it possible (in a class or package, say) to increase the font size based on the current font size? For example, if `\normalsize` is currently in effect, it would set the current font size to `\large`; if `\large` is in force, set it to `\Large`; and so on.

Comment: Check the `relsize` package.